# Draw bitmap to polygon using canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I have a custom view. It has many quadrilaterals (not rectangle). I have to draw bitmap to each quadrilateral. Now, I'm using matrix to draw bitmap to quadrilateral but it's distorted. Something like this:

```
float[] src = new float[] {
                            0.0f, 0.0f,
                            0.0f, (float) trimBitmap.getHeight(),
                            (float) trimBitmap.getWidth(), (float) trimBitmap.getHeight(),
                            (float) trimBitmap.getWidth(), 0.0f };
float[] dst = new float[] {
                            frame.get(0).x * ratio, frame.get(0).y * ratio,
                            frame.get(1).x * ratio, frame.get(1).y * ratio,
                            frame.get(2).x * ratio, frame.get(2).y * ratio,
                            frame.get(3).x * ratio, frame.get(3).y * ratio };

matrix.setPolyToPoly(src, 0, dst, 0, 4);
canvas.drawBitmap(trimBitmap, matrix, picturePaint);
```

I'm trying to use BitmapShader but don't how it works?
Any advice for me?

**EDIT** I'm trying to use BitmapShader like this

```
Path path = new Path();

path.moveTo(picture.getFrame().get(0).x * ratio, picture.getFrame().get(0).y * ratio);
path.lineTo(picture.getFrame().get(1).x * ratio, picture.getFrame().get(1).y * ratio);
path.lineTo(picture.getFrame().get(2).x * ratio, picture.getFrame().get(2).y * ratio);
path.lineTo(picture.getFrame().get(3).x * ratio, picture.getFrame().get(3).y * ratio);
path.lineTo(picture.getFrame().get(0).x * ratio, picture.getFrame().get(0).y * ratio);

BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(trimBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
picturePaint.setShader(shader);
canvas.drawPath(path, picturePaint);
```

Thanks.

Comment: paint.setShader(yourBitmapShader) and then canvas.drawPath(path, paint)

Comment: @pskink: I did but got a very strange result. Can you guide me how to config the matrix to fit the bitmap to quadrilateral. Please help, I am sick of this problem.

Comment: "strange" has different meaning for different people, i don't know your definition

Comment: @pskink: It draws a small part of bitmap and then replicate the edge color. I think I must config a matrix to map bitmap's coordinates with quadrilateral's coordinates.

Comment: @pskink: I showed my code in question. Thanks for your enthusiasm!

Comment: Your code is ok, use local Matrix in the shader

Comment: @pskink: Do you mean: shader.setLocalMatrix(getMatrix()); ?

Comment: not getMatrix(). use scaled Matrix, for example Matrix.postScale(ratio, ratio);

Comment: @pskink: Aha, may be this is the point. I will try out. Thank you once again.